# Flask-WTF dynamic select field gives "None" as a string

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have an empty select field that has choices that I define during run time:

```
myfield = SelectField('myfield', validators=[Optional()])
```

I'm trying to have this work with a GET request which looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def myresponse():
    form = myform(csrf_enabled=False)
    form.myfield.choices = (('', ''), ('apples', 'apples'), ('pears', 'pears'))
```

Then when I try to validate on an empty form. (I go to myapp.com with no GET parameters)

```
    if not form.validate():
        return search_with_no_parameters()
    else:
        return search_with_parameters(form) #this gets run
```

When my search_with_parameters function tries to use the form variables, it checks to make sure that the `form.myfield.data` is not Falsey (not an empty string). If it is not Falsey, a search with that parameter is done. If it is Falsey, that parameter is ignored. However, on an empty form submission, `form.myfield.data` is `"None"` as a string. And a search with `"None"` is done. I could validate against the `"None"` string but I think this defeats the purpose of using this module in the first place. Is there any way to make this just return an empty string or the real `None` value?

Comment: Not that it helps, but it seems to be by design: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/tests/fields.py#L290

Comment: My pull request which fixes this was just merged: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/288

Answer (score 9):

I have found that adding a `default` parameter of the empty string solves the problem.

It appears that this is necessary to support the empty string as a choice/option with a `SelectField`.

Example:

```
myfield = wtf.fields.SelectField(
    u"My Field",
    validators=[wtf.validators.Optional()],
    choices=[(('', ''), ('apples', 'apples'), ('pears', 'pears'))],
    default=''
)
```

Comment: Having to do this is arguably a bug in WTForms, since returning `"None"` as a string is just very odd indeed.

Comment: Not obvious solution, I also think it's a bug

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I made a workaround for this. I added a `coerce` definition to the field and changed the empty value from `''` to `0` like this:

```
myfield = SelectField('myfield', validators=[Optional()], coerce=int)
...
form.myfield.choices = ((0, ''), (1, 'apples'), (2, 'pears'))
```

Of course, this only works because my real data was using integers as the values. I'm not sure how this would work if my data was strings.